# Apply jquery script only on specific tags

Tags: jquery, html, navigation, tags

I am using this jquery script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Fix Errors - http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/01/quick-tip-prevent-animation-queue-buildup/

    //Remove outline from links
    $("a").click(function(){
        $(this).blur();
    });

    //When mouse rolls over
    $("li").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({height:'80px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'})
    });

    //When mouse is removed
    $("li").mouseout(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({height:'220px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'})
    });

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="nav1" class="top_nav" style="position:absolute; left:80px;">
    <ul>
        <li class="green">
            <p><a href="#"></a></p>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

**Question:** My question is this: The above jquery script should apply only on div having ID "nav1". But It apply all "li" that I use in my page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to apply Jquery to Div having **ID**  "nav1"

```
   $("#nav1 li").click(function(){});
```

Comment: You write #nav li, Is should use #nav1 li of #nav li

Comment: @BigTech it should be `#nav1 li`

Answer (score 0):

If you select `$('li')` it will select all list items on your page, which you learn by now, instead target `<li>` inside div `#nav1` like on example below

```
$("#nav1 li").mouseover(function(){...
```

Additional info - [jQuery Child Selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)